# How to handle static files handler in Tornado with several static folders?

Tags: python-2.7, url-routing, tornado, file-handling

My current routing tables is like below:

```
routing_table = [
        ("/api/ping", PingHandler),
        ("/css/(.*)", StaticFileHandler, {
             "path": "my-website-path/css"
        }),
        ("/js/(.*)", StaticFileHandler, {
             "path": "my-website-path/js"
        }),
        ("/fonts/(.*)", StaticFileHandler, {
             "path": "my-website-path/fonts"
        })
```

I would like to use only one regex to handle my static files.
Something like below ?

```
routing_table = [
        ("/api/ping", PingHandler),
        ("/(css|js|fonts)/(.*)", StaticFileHandler, {
             "path": "my-website-path/$1"
        })
```

How can I do that?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe try subclassing the StaticFileHandler to specify the folders you want

Comment: Actually... I'm pretty sure tornado routes support regex, but using Nginx/Apache to serve static assets would be more optimal

Comment: Good idea, I gonna subclass the StaticFileHandler  if there is no other solution. Tornado routes support regex for sure and I would prefer that Tornado handles by itself all files of the projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `RequestHandler` pass all matches as a positional arguments to the http-verb function. Since the `StaticFileHandler` extends it and you have 2 captured groups, your code won't work as expected. So the regex needs to be changed, step by step:

1. match entire path: `/(.*)`
2. first part should be fonts, js or css: `((jss|css|fonts)/.*`
3. the inner group should not be captured - make use of [`?:`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax): `((?:jss|css|fonts)/.*`

The code

```
routing_table = [
        ("/api/ping", PingHandler),
        ("/((?:css|js|fonts)/.*)", StaticFileHandler, {
             "path": "my-website-path"
        }
```

---

Keep in mind, that the [`StaitcFileHandler`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.StaticFileHandler) (as @cricket_007 mentioned)...

> This handler is intended primarily for use in development and light-duty file serving; for heavy traffic it will be more efficient to use a dedicated static file server (such as nginx or Apache). We support the HTTP Accept-Ranges mechanism to return partial content (because some browsers require this functionality to be present to seek in HTML5 audio or video).

Comment: Don't worry I know that but I will not have a heavy trafic. Thanks for your help. It works like a charm ;)